# SQLGrammarException: No value specified for parameter 1 hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I have 1-1 mapping:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "messageDetails")
public MessageEntry getMessageEntry() {
    return messageEntry;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public MessageDetails getMessageDetails() {
    return messageDetails;
}
```

I want to delete some messageDetails:

```
        if (entries.size()>0)
        sess.createQuery(
                "DELETE MessageDetails d " +
                "WHERE d.messageEntry IN (:entries)")
                .setParameterList("entries",entries).executeUpdate();
```

where entries is List.

I get this SQL in logs:

```
19:48:13,594 DEBUG SQL:104 - delete from MessageDetails where id in (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,
 ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,
 ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,
 ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,
 ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,
 ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,
 ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,
 ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,
 ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,
 ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)
```

and this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy18.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:413)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.executeUpdate(StatelessSessionImpl.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.kriyak.hbm.Archive.updateFilesStateless(Archive.java:228)
    at org.kriyak.parser.IndexArchiveFast.main(IndexArchiveFast.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
```

I use stateless session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by joining the collection to the query, then operating on the joined column:

```
SELECT a FROM Anything a JOIN a.thisIsACollection coll WHERE coll IN :param
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that hibernate will automatically convert collection to comma separated parameter values.

```
 sess.createQuery(
                "DELETE MessageDetails d " +
                "WHERE d.messageEntry IN (:entries)")
                .setParameterList("entries",entries).executeUpdate();
```

for entries i would suggest to convert it to comma separated values or use seperate delete statement for each entries in batch mode.

Comment: this construct worked for me in other select cases. Here is part of text from manual: Bind multiple values to a named query parameter. The Hibernate type of the parameter is first detected via the usage/position in the query and if not sufficient secondly guessed from the class of the first object in the collection. This is useful for binding a list of values to an expression such as foo.bar in (:value_list).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the other method signature where u pass collections object Type as parameter

```
setParameterList(String name, Collection vals, Type type)
```